# Cannot force instantiation of specialized template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In a **static library** I declared a template in Class.h then I specialized some methods in Class.cpp. I want to use this class in a project linking to this library.

I put the specialization in a .cpp file to avoid errors like "already declared" (???) end at the end of the same .cpp I declared the existence of the specialization once everything is known for this class. Here is the code:

**Class.h**

```
#ifndef __CLASS_H__
#define __CLASS_H__
template<class T>
class Class
{
public:
    ~Class(){}
    Class(){}
    //...
    void method1()
    { /* unspecialized job here */ }
};
#endif
```

**Class.cpp**

```
#include "Class.h"

template<>
void Class<bool>::method1()
{
    /* Specialized job for bool here */
}

// Declare that the class is specialized for bool
template class Class<bool>;
```

Now, in my project using the library, when I try to instantiate an object of `class Class<bool>`, it still use the *unspecialized* method.

What is the problem? Is the use of "template" at the end of the .cpp file correct?

I use gcc 4.8/4.9 on Kubuntu/Raspbian if it has an importance and I use C++11.

Comment: You need to at least declare the specialization in the header (the implementation can still go into the source file, or else be in the header, marked `inline`). Otherwise, your program violates ODR, and is therefore ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: Put another way, client code `#include`-ing `Class.h` sees nothing therein to justify *not* instantiating its own version of the unspecialised template.  You have to inhibit that by showing it the declaration.

Comment: "Declare that the class is specialized for bool" - `template class Class<bool>;` does nothing of that sort. Also, do not use reserved names as include guards.

Comment: Not related to the topic, but I would suggest not to use names with double underscores, or with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter. They are reserved for implementations and may cause undefined behavior (see 17.6.4.3.2 of the C++11 Standard).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Langr for the point about the `__GUARD_H__`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template specializations

```
template<>
void Class<bool>::method1()
{
    /* Specialized job for bool here */
}

// Declare that the class is specialized for bool
template class Class<bool>;
```

are seen only in Class.cpp. If `Class<bool>` is used anywhere else in your code, those specializations are not visible there. Hence, the generic class template is used to instantiate `Class<bool>`.

If you want the specializations to be visible to all the files where `Class<bool>` is used, move them to Class.h. At that point, Class.cpp won't be necessary any more unless it has code other than the lines above.

Comment: *"move them to Class.h.  At that point, Class.cpp won't be necessary any more."* - alternatively, you can move only the declaration to the .h, and that might be desired for the same reasons a .cpp might be preferred for a non-templated class (i.e. less code/dependencies in header, clients only need to relink - rather than recompile - to pick up changed specialisation behaviour...).

Comment: Thanks! I added a declaration in the header and now the methods are seen from the outside world. The definition is still in the source file so it doesn't appear multiple time and doesn't generate a compilation error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use extern templates for the specialization to be effective.

In your cpp you have the specialization and this line:

```
template struct MyClass<bool>;
```

Then add to the header:

```
extern template struct MyClass<bool>;
```

Now the compiler will be told to not instantiate the template but to pick up the instantiated one in your cpp.